# Windows Wi-Fi able to see available networks, but not authenticate

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, usb

As a volunteer, I'm trying to setup a number of donated older computers in a school with Wi-Fi access using a number of [identical Buffalo USB adapters](http://www.buffalotech.com/products/wireless/usb-adapters/airstation-highpower-n150-wireless-usb-adapter). A Windows XP and Windows 7 computer each have no problems, using the drivers supplied on the CD by the manufacturer, and a Ubuntu 14 computer worked fine without anything else.

On one Windows 7 box (an [HP S5510F](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02106642&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en)) I'm having an inexplicable problem I've never seen before. I installed the drivers and the USB stick like on the other systems, and it is able to view all the nearby network SSIDs. However, for some reason it cannot connect to the network I need it to connect to. It comes up with a typical Windows 7 dialog complaining that it cannot connect, but it comes up suspiciously fast like it's not even trying to actually connect.

I was able to connect to at least one other network with this same computer, but it refuses to connect to this one specific network! All of the computers near it are working fine, so I have the right password. I've entered it multiple times, very very carefully. I've had someone else enter the password. It simply does not work with this one SSID.

Any suggestions what the problem could be? This is **maddening**.

I'm tempted to wipe the thing down to factory defaults again, but since that's how I started configuring this machine in the first place, I somehow doubt that will be effective.

Comment: There are still a lot of variables to consider, but 1) have you tried the USB adapter on another PC? 2) Have you tried another adapter on this PC? 3) Was the type of network and security of the network you were able to connect the same as the one that doesn't work (ie for example Wireless N with WPA2-AES)?

Comment: I got a batch of five of those USB adapters. I tried swapping them with other machines to no effect, and they continue to work on the other donated systems in the room.

Comment: Ok! ... and what about the third question above?

Comment: I can't really answer that until I visit the site and check, so I held back on responding.

Comment: It's very important to test if it can connect to any other network. Perhaps a non-secured wifi connection is the best test you can do as the next step